# Using a headset with a Macbook pro mid 2009

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones

Does this Macbook support any kind of dual 3.5mm connection headsets ? Acording to this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201938) there is in fact an audio in port but I have never seen that symbol for "audio in" been used

Answer (score 2):

That symbol indicates "Audio line in/optical digital audio in port".

It is a combo port, and it supports Optical connection.

[image: OPTICAL]